# Amplification of magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

can we by any means amplify magnetic signal as we can with electric signal. As both electric and magnetic field can be represented in the form of a wave the analogy seems to be natural.

I want the input and output as magnetic signal.

Comment: Amplifying electric signals is normally done by manipulating electric charges (i.e. electrons). However as far as we know there are no magnetic charges.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to amplify the magnetic field, though the mechanism is not same as for electrical signal amplification, but still they are fruitful. 
compression:- since a magnetic flux through a surface remains conserved, if we compress the field lines or stretch (or fold) the field line then we can increase the energy by working against the field force. in this process even the field topology will remain invariant. By linear winding of field lines we can create a toroidal field.
another important way is amplification of [Alfven wave](http://iopscience.iop.org/0032-1028/14/5/004/pdf/0032-1028_14_5_004.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I presume your idea revolves around permanent magnets, if so stacking decreasing sized magnets in a pyramid configuration grants you a powerful localized field at the smallest point. Halbach configurations allow for combined field manipulation which comes with the downside of slowly degrading the total field strength over time.

Please do let me know what you find as I am researching a similer querry.

Answer (score 0):

Electrical amplification is about using an input signal to modulate a larger amount of power that comes from a separate power supply of some sort.

And yes, there is such a thing as a [magnetic amplifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_amplifier) that works on a very similar principle (even though the inputs and outputs are usually electrical). But you can't get an output value that's greater than the sum of the input values (control signal plus power source).

Comment: if the input/output is electrical signal, then it is not what the question asks. the question is about magnifying the magnetic field, not using a magnetic field to magnify an electric signal

Comment: @NikosM.: But the point is that the fundamental mechanism is magnetic; the fact that the signals are transduced from and to electrical signals is merely an implementation detail.

Comment: Dave you misunderstand the question, what saves it from my downvoting is that you mention that it actually amplifies electric signals and **not magnetic fields**

Comment: @NikosM.: The question is ambiguous, and I think *you* have misunderstood it. I interpret it as asking about amplifying a magnetic *signal*, using a direct analogy to electrical *signal* amplification. You seem to be interpreting it as being about concentrating a magnetic *field* (as an analogy to doing the same thing to an electric field?). I guess we'll just have to wait until the OP clarifies his intent.

Comment: From the question "*can we by any means **amplify magnetic field** as we can with electric signal*"? (emphasis mine) It is clear what is asked.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But, I am really sorry for the ambiguity. I want my input and output signal to be magnetic.

Comment: @user1964232: Can you describe in a little more detail what the concept of "magnetic signal" means to you?